# Javascript User-input for operators not outputing the integers

Tags: javascript

I'm supposed to take a few numbers and give them out in a list prompt.

EDIT, SOLVED thank you

Comment: So concatenate it as a string, you did it in one place....

Comment: What is your desired result? You replace `num1` and `num2` by their corresponding numbers in exactly the same way you already did in the second `document.write` line. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

concatenate the variables with the operators like you did with `"Num 1= " + num1` , and you can do the math directly in the `document.write` without reassigning `result` each time :

```js
var entry;
var average;
var total = 0;

entry = prompt("enter first number");
entry = parseInt(entry);
var num1 = entry;
total = total + num1;

entry = prompt("enter second number");
entry = parseInt(entry);
var num2 = entry;
total = total + num2;

average = parseInt(total / 2);
document.write("<h2>Arithmetic and operators</h2>")
document.write('Num 1 = ' + num1 + ' <br> Num 2 = ' + num2 + ' <br> Average num = ' + average + '<br>')

document.write(num1 + ' + ' + num2 + ' = ' + ( num1 + num2 ));
document.write("<br>")

document.write(num1 + ' - ' + num2 + ' = ' + ( num1 - num2 ));
document.write("<br>")

document.write(num1 + ' / ' + num2 + ' = ' + ( num1 / num2 ));
document.write("<br>")

document.write(num1 + ' % ' + num2 + ' = ' + ( num1 % num2 ));
document.write("<br>")

document.write(num1 + ' * ' + num2 + ' = ' + ( num1 * num2 ));
document.write("<br>")
```

Comment: Needs to be intro to js style code cant be using stuff i dont know yet

Comment: ok, i updated the answer for a simpler version  ( @epascarello )